# postfix: mails to gmx and web.de can not be send

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, log-files

since some days I can't longer send mails to gmx or web.de ... I don't know why, gmail and so on is still working. I find this in the mail.log :

```
Sep 24 11:27:10 root postfix/smtp[18395]: 4AA2AA06DD: host mx-ha02.web.de[212.227.17.8] refused to talk to me: 421-web.de (mxweb105) Nemesis ESMTP Service not available 421 Requested action aborted: local error in processing

Sep 24 11:27:11 root postfix/smtp[18395]: 4AA2AA06DD: to=<*****@web.de>, relay=mx-ha03.web.de[212.227.15.17]:25, delay=2.1, delays=0.05/0.01/2/0, dsn=4.0.0, status=deferred (host mx-ha03.web.de[212.227.15.17] refused to talk to me: 421-web.de (mxweb003) Nemesis ESMTP Service not available 421 Requested action aborted: local error in processing)
```

whats that and what have I to do ? :/

thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

Postfix logs the banner of the remote SMTP server and the error message that is generated by the remote mailserver:

> 421-web.de (mxweb105) Nemesis ESMTP Service not available
>   421 Requested action aborted: local error in processing

`421` is a short [SMTP status code](http://www.iana.org/assignments/smtp-enhanced-status-codes/smtp-enhanced-status-codes.xhtml) and is defined in in [RFC 2821](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt)  as temporary and transient status/error and your mailserver should queue the message and attempt delivery at a later date.

*Requested action aborted: local error in processing* seems an error on their side.

Your messages are not outright refused with a permanent error.

Comment: but why this is only for gmx and web ? :/ and since some days and it is still not sent :/

Comment: @SoFa7 We are not 1und1 and we do not know why their mail servers are malfunctioning. If you really want to get this mail delivered, you should contact their postmaster.

Comment: The "why" is easy. Two case are possible: they both have a technical issue (less likely) or gmx and web.de share the underlying infrastructure (they use same physical servers) and this infra has an outage. This sometimes happen normally so don't afraid. 421 is a temporary error, your server will try to deliver those messages later.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've made it onto some sort of reputation blacklist, or both providers have locally decided to block you based on the mails you're sending.

A lot of the well known blacklists have a means to lookup your IP address and then optionally give you the ability to request removal. You should also check you've not inadvertently become an open relay.

Comment: how can I check if my IP is on a blacklist ?

Comment: Use (for example) http://www.anti-abuse.org/multi-rbl-check/

Comment: hmm , everywhere "not listed" :/

Comment: It's not neccessarily a blacklist problem. "Nemesis ESMTP Service not available" tells me gmx.at and web.de share the underlying infrastructure and it /had a technical issue at the time when the OP tried to send that letter. 

@SoFa7 when you face with a problem like this it's always a good idea to check your blacklist status but it's not neccesarily the root of your problem so consider it just as an additional info.

Comment: Hmm, I am using SendGrid to send out all my e-mails. The domain name of the e-mail address sent from (our organisation), the domain name of sendgrid and the IP address sent from (retrieved via sending an e-mail to myself and look into the headers) are not listed on the site mentioned. But a lot of e-mails are being deferred with error code 421 `Reject due to policy violations` for gmx.de and web.de
Any ideas?